# Cyclic dependencies on multi-module maven project

Tags: java, dependency-management, multi-module, cyclic-dependency

I have been writing a **very** simple blockchain in java for the last few weeks as a maven project with Intellij. When I began this project, I was okay with everything residing in a single module, even though there are technically two artifacts that need to be built for the project to work (An executable .jar for the application/control logic and a .war for all of the p2p stuff deployed via tomcat container). I used separate profiles to build the .jar and .war, and executed/deployed them manually.

I have, however, grown tired of this and believe that splitting this up into a multi-module project (a .war, .jar and .ear? maybe..) is the only way to achieve my goal of being able to build and execute/deploy everything all at once with a single command. I have begun to do this, but have become confused by cyclic dependencies between the two child modules. I have code on the application side that depends on the network side, and code on the network side that depends on the application side. How can I resolve this by creating another module and thus another pom.xml? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Please bear with me, as I am still a novice in java/maven, this is my first real crack at an application with any degree of complexity.

Comment: If you are using Spring, then better to go with SpringBoot project as a solution on both sides network application and server application as it would take care of the dependency management by itself offering convention over configuration approach, If i am correct your war should be using JAR as a dependency, so everything should go on in the pom you are using for your war file

Comment: I am not using Spring, though when I first began this project I did consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your child modules c1 and c2 dependent on each other, meaning a class or packages, then the common package should be in a separate module c3. Add c3 as dependency in both c1 and c2 project.

you can not add c1 as dependency in c2 and c2 as dependency in c1. Because when maven tries to analyze your code, it can not find the which module to build first due to this cyclic dependency.

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I was looking for. I understand why the cyclic dependency can't exist, I just get confused when thinking about how to craft the module hierarchy to remedy it. So say c1 is the jar module and c2 is the war module. If c1 needs the nodes package from c2, and c2 needs the util package from c1, to avoid a cyclic dependency I would  both packages into a 3rd module?

Comment: yes. Thats correct.  we should keep the common codes in a separate module.  we normally call these kind of modules with names such as "core, shared, etc.,"